# cant able to get the blob stored image into image format(MySql AND php)?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am trying to get the image which is stored in the blob format in Mysql Database.I am using the following code.
**index.php**

```
<img src='image.php?questionid=questionid&question=question1&answer=answer1&author=myname' />
```

**image.php**

```
<?php
require_once('dbconfiguration.php');
$sql="SELECT image FROM tablename WHERE questionid='{$_GET['questionid']}' and question='{$_GET['question']}' and answer='{$_GET['answer']}' and author='{$_GET['author']}'";
$STH = $DBH->query($sql);  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$row = $STH->fetch();  
ob_clean();
header("content-type: image/jpg") ; 
echo $row['image'] ; 
?>
```

In index.php I didn't get any image.So When I enter the URL for image.php I am getting the following error in forefox.

```
The image “URL” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

I am using php5.3 and mysql 5.1.36 .

What I did wrong.I went through almost all forums and no clues.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<?php
require_once('dbconfiguration.php');
$sql="SELECT image FROM tablename WHERE questionid='{$_GET['questionid']}' and question='{$_GET['question']}' and answer='{$_GET['answer']}' and author='{$_GET['author']}'";
$STH = $DBH->query($sql);  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$row = $STH->fetch();  
ob_clean();
header("content-type: image/jpg") ; 
echo $row['image'] ; 
?>
```

As your database field is called **image** not **Efaq_image**

Comment: Thats the old one.When I change the table field name I changed this also in php.Not updated here.please  see the updated quesion now.

Comment: Your created query is correct too? and are you sure your blob data is a valid jpg image?

Comment: Yes.I stored only jpg and when I remove the header I can see the binary datas in my screen.

Comment: Thanks Frederick Behrends.Now I fixed the issue.Its because I added the slashes when I try to insert an image.But I didnt remove the slashes when I try to get the images.Now Its fixed.Thanks for your help.